# Problema de sintaxe ou bug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Eu estou usando `onclick` para executar um JavaScript quando um botão é clicado no dropdown-menu.

O problema está na *view*:

[image: screenshot indicando erro]

Código completo da imagem acima:

```
/*Linha 1*/ <div id="context-menu4">
    /*Linha 2*/ <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        /*Linha 3*/ <li style="cursor:pointer" onclick="ApagarImagem4()"><a tabindex="-1">Apagar</a></li>
        /*Linha 4*/ <li style="cursor:pointer" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DownloadImagem", "Account", new {imagem = "Image4" })'"><a tabindex="-1">Baixar imagem</a></li>
        /*Linha 5*/ <li><a tabindex="-1">Something else here</a></li>
        /*Linha 6*/ <li class="divider"></li>
        /*Linha 7*/ <li><a tabindex="-1">Separated link</a></li>
    /*Linha 8*/ </ul>
/*Linha 9*/ </div>
```

Código JavaScript:

```
function ApagarImagem4(){

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Account/Apagar_Imagem4',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { imagem :"Imagem4" },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.Success)
            { alert("Sucesso")}

        }
    });
}
```

Parece que não gostou parêntese "ApagarImagem4()". O problema foi na linha 3.

Na lista de erro, mostra um aviso amarelo:

[image: Unterminated string constant]

Então, quando reinicia Visual Studio, o aviso desaparece. As vezes quando eu mando executar, ele mostra esse aviso.

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Uma dica: evite usar imagens.

Comment: como está seu js ?

Comment: Oi @JcSaint, editei meu post, lá adicionei código Js.

Comment: Você tentou colocar `;` no fim ? `onclick="suaFuncao();"`

Comment: Oi @JcSaint, sim já tentei colocar ponto vírgula (;) e continua o mesmo

Comment: Já tentou remover os parenteses ?

Comment: Sim, continua o mesmo Problema

Comment: As vezes some o problema